# How to show a Dialog when a Marker was clicked from Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to show a custom dialog box from the Google Maps through the Google Maps Android API v2 once a custom marker from the map was clicked. The custom marker will show the current traffic condition in the location where it was placed. The custom Dialog contains the name of the place, the current northbound and southbound traffic condition of the road, some advisory if available (like, road is under construction, etc.), and the time when the traffic was updated. All these data came from an XML file and was stored in the sqlite database. My problem now is, when I click on any of the markers, it only shows the Dialog of the first data in the query. I know that my query was right because the markers contains the right icons with regards to traffic condition. I guess the problem is only on the looping process. I also tried using for loop but the same output was generated. Can anyone help me to achieve my goal? Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapViewActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    public static final LatLng CITYHALL = new LatLng(07.0644444, 125.6077778);
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_mapview);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private Boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    private void setUpMap() {

        if (isOnline()) {

            String query = "SELECT * FROM TrafficCondition";
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("_dds", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            final Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(MapViewActivity.this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.mapview_marker_dialog);
            d.setTitle("Traffic Information");

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    final double lat = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("lat"));
                    final double lng = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("lng"));
                    final int north_condition = c.getInt(c
                            .getColumnIndex("north_condition"));
                    final int south_condition = c.getInt(c
                            .getColumnIndex("south_condition"));
                    final String north_advisory = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("north_advisory"));
                    final String south_advisory = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("south_advisory"));
                    final String icon = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("icon"));
                    final String traffic_last_updated = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("traffic_last_updated"));

                    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
                    final Date app_last_updated = new Date(c.getLong(c
                            .getColumnIndex("app_last_updated")));
                    final String appLastUpdated = dateFormat
                            .format(app_last_updated);

                    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset(new String(
                                    icon + ".png"))));


                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CITYHALL,
                            12));

                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String nNoData = "NorthBound: No Data";
                            String nLightCon = "NorthBound: Light";
                            String nModerateCon = "NorthBound: Moderate";
                            String nHeavyCon = "NorthBound: Heavy";

                            String sNoData = "SouthBound: No Data";
                            String sLightCon = "SouthBound: Light";
                            String sModerateCon = "SouthBound: Moderate";
                            String sHeavyCon = "SouthBound: Heavy";

                            TextView title = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.traffic_con_node_title);
                            title.setText(name);

                            TextView nTrafficCon = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.n_traffic_con);
                            TextView sTrafficCon = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.s_traffic_con);

                            TextView nAdvisoryTitle = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.n_traffic_con_ad_title);
                            TextView sAdvisoryTitle = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.s_traffic_con_ad_title);

                            TextView nTrafficConAd = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.n_traffic_con_ad_content);
                            TextView sTrafficConAd = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.s_traffic_con_ad_content);

                            TextView TrafficLastUpdated = (TextView) d
                                    .findViewById(R.id.traffic_con_last_updated);

                            if (north_condition == 0) {
                                nTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_bg_nodata);
                                nTrafficCon.setText(nNoData);
                            } else if (north_condition == 1) {
                                nTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_bg_light);
                                nTrafficCon.setText(nLightCon);
                            } else if (north_condition == 2) {
                                nTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_bg_moderate);
                                nTrafficCon.setText(nModerateCon);
                            } else if (north_condition == 3) {
                                nTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_bg_heavy);
                                nTrafficCon.setText(nHeavyCon);
                            }

                            if (south_condition == 0) {
                                sTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s_bg_nodata);
                                sTrafficCon.setText(sNoData);
                            } else if (south_condition == 1) {
                                sTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s_bg_light);
                                sTrafficCon.setText(sLightCon);
                            } else if (south_condition == 2) {
                                sTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s_bg_moderate);
                                sTrafficCon.setText(sModerateCon);
                            } else if (south_condition == 3) {
                                sTrafficCon
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s_bg_heavy);
                                sTrafficCon.setText(sHeavyCon);
                            }

                            String empty = "null";

                            if ((north_advisory.trim().length() > 0)
                                    && (!north_advisory.equals(empty))) {
                                nAdvisoryTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                nTrafficConAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                nTrafficConAd.setText(north_advisory);
                            } else if (nAdvisoryTitle.equals(null)) {
                                nAdvisoryTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                nTrafficConAd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            if ((south_advisory.trim().length() > 0)
                                    && (!south_advisory.equals(empty))) {
                                sAdvisoryTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                sTrafficConAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                sTrafficConAd.setText(south_advisory);
                            } else {
                                sAdvisoryTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                sTrafficConAd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            TrafficLastUpdated.setText("Updated "
                                    + traffic_last_updated + ".");

                            d.show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this, "No connection..",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In class ItemizedOverlay there's a function on onTap(). Use that.

Comment: I cannot used that because I am using the latest version of Google Maps API which is version 2.

Comment: I can now show the dialog through the given code above. The real problem is, it doesn't shows the correct contents in every dialog. All the data of the markers and the dialog came from the database. Each marker when clicked, should show a dialog box with a different data from the other depending on what's the data inside the database. But it only shows one data from the database (i think the very 1st one) when any of the available markers was clicked.

Comment: How did you do this in the end?

Comment: Don't access local database in the UI thread. It causes bad user experience.

Comment: And don't call moveCamera and setOnMarkerClickListener in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener once for every data element. You should only call it once. You should store the data from the DB in a Map indexed by marker ID. Then when the user taps on a marker, you can retrieve it and display the appropriate information.